# Mono HTTPListener throws exception when using self signed SSL certificate

Tags: c#, linux, ssl, mono

I wrote a little web server on Linux using the Mono HTTPListener class. It works fine for http requests. However, if I use a self-signed SSL certificate (created with openssl and installed with httpcfg) it will throw an un-catchable exception as soon as the request forom a browser comes in.

The exception is:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The client stopped the handshake.
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslServerStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0xb4b079c8 + 0x001cf> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0xb4b07428 + 0x0005f> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace SSLTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main ()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpListener l = new HttpListener ();
                l.Prefixes.Add ("https://*:8443/");
                l.Start ();

                Console.WriteLine("Server is running.");
                while (l.IsListening)
                {
                    //create the worker thread
                    HttpListenerContext ctx = l.GetContext();   //.GetContext() blocks until something comes in
                    if(ctx != null)
                    {
                        if(ctx.Request.RemoteEndPoint != null)
                        {
                            Thread workerThread = new Thread(() => RunWorker(ctx));
                            workerThread.Start();
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Server is stopped.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Exception in Main: " + ex);
            }
        }


        static void RunWorker(HttpListenerContext ctx)
        {
            try
            {
                if(ctx.Request != null)
                {
                    if(ctx.Request.RemoteEndPoint != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Got request from " + ctx.Request.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                        string rstr = "Test Website!\n" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                        byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                        if(buf!=null)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("@Exception in RunWorker: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is the case when I am using a browser for the first time. The browser will show something like "Unsafe certificate! Do you want to continue (not recommended)?". If I click on Yes and restart the crashed server app it will work from that moment on.

How can I fix this?

Also, I am not able to catch this exception with a try block. It will always terminate my application. How can I prevent that?

Comment: I've definitely got a similar problem here, although with a CA signed certificate, not self-signed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604945/how-to-i-catch-ssl-exceptions-in-a-mono-httplistener-server

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed by an unreleased bug fix https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52675... although I have not had a chance to test.

I have seen this as well and am currently trying to find a way to handle the exception.  This looks to be a bug in Mono.

It occurs when certificate verification fails in any way.

I obtained a CA signed cert which fixed the problem as long as the certificate common name (dns) is the same as the dns used in the URL I'm trying to send a get request to.  If I instead specify the public IP address in the url (which the cert is not registered with) the mono app will crash with an unhandled exception.

One option we're considering is implementing a TCP based webserver which would use a TcpListener instead of the heavy HttpListener which would in turn fix other problems we're seeing with mono httplistener prefixes not working correctly when bound to the internal IP behind a NAT.  This would mean the cert could be bound pro-grammatically as well, it just takes more work.

Below is a very rough version of what this might look like.  By no means is this a finished product but it may serve to help others on this same path...  I'll have to do this in two answers, this is the tcp web server.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Example.Lib.Net
{
    internal class TcpWebServer : IDisposable
    {
        private TcpListener m_Listener = null;
        private bool m_IsSSL = false;
        private X509Certificate2 m_ServerCertificate = null;

        internal X509Certificate2 ServerCertificate
        {
            get { return m_ServerCertificate; }
            set { m_ServerCertificate = value; }
        }

        internal void Start(string ip, int port, bool useSsl = false)
        {
            if (useSsl) // for player streams always use ssl to
            {
                m_IsSSL = true;
                m_ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2("./cert/cert.pfx", "pass");

                X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                store.Add(m_ServerCertificate);
                store.Close();
            }

            IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Any;
            if (ip != "*") IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out ipAddr);

            try
            {
                m_Listener = new TcpListener(ipAddr, port);
                m_Listener.Start();
                m_Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnClientAccepted, m_Listener);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private void OnClientAccepted(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            TcpListener listener = ar.AsyncState as TcpListener;

            if (listener == null)
                return;

            TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
            client.ReceiveBufferSize = 65535;
            client.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 65535;

            TcpWebConnection con = new TcpWebConnection(client, this, m_IsSSL);

            listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnClientAccepted, listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up implementing the tcp based web server and bound the ssl certificate programmatically.  The bug I posted above would fix the problem however that bug was found in 4.8 of Mono and has not been implemented any in revision since.  Not sure why there is no motivation to implement it.  I suggest taking the route of creating your own TCP Listener which parses http / https, it takes some work but is worth it in the end.  You could also pull down the mono source, implement the bug fix above yourself and build your own copy...

Comment: can you share your implementation approach? did you manage to implement a cross platform SSL enabled web server?

Comment: Yes it is SSL enabled and does support cross platform however it is by no means finished nor does it closely follow http / https official specs.  It works for what I need and I add additional functionality as needed.  Probably not good enough to post here as an overall solution.

Comment: I take it back, I'll update my answer with the code.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I think this is now fixed. I just tried it with mono 5.16 and it's working fine. Finally!!

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for the heads up Gerhard!

Answer (score 0):

This is the tcp web connection code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;

using Example.Lib.Common;
using Example.Lib.Models;

namespace Example.Lib.Net
{
    internal enum RequestType
    {
        None = 0,
        GET = 1,
        POST = 2,
        OPTIONS = 3
    }

    internal class TcpWebConnection : IDisposable
    {
        #region private members

        private bool m_IsDisposed = false;
        private bool m_IsSSL = false;
        private bool m_HasHeaders = false;
        private bool m_FileCreated = false;
        private bool m_IsFileUpload = false;
        private RequestType m_RequestType = RequestType.None;
        private string m_ReadData = string.Empty;
        private string m_Request = string.Empty;
        private string m_RemoteIP = string.Empty;
        private string m_AbsoluteURI = string.Empty;
        private string m_ContentType = string.Empty;
        private string m_TempFilename = string.Empty;
        private byte[] m_EndBoundaryBytes = null;
        private byte[] m_StartBoundaryBytes = null;
        private int m_ContentLength = 0;
        private long m_StartBoundaryIndex = -1;
        private long m_EndBoundaryIndex = -1;
        private long m_BytesRead = 0;
        private NameValueCollection m_QueryString = null;
        private string[] m_Segments = new string[1];
        private string m_HttpVersion = "HTTP/1.1";
        private byte[] m_PostData = null;
        private byte[] m_Buffer = new byte[65535];
        private ReadWriteBuffer m_TempBuffer;
        private FileStream m_FileStream = null;
        private MemoryStream m_FullBuffer = new MemoryStream();
        private TcpClient m_Client = null;
        private System.IO.Stream m_NetworkStream = null;
        private TcpWebServer m_Parent = null;
        private Thread m_Thread_Read = null;
        private Timer m_Timer_Check = null;
        private DateTime m_LastRead = DateTime.Now;
        private AutoResetEvent m_WaitHandle_Write;

        #endregion private members

        #region constructors

        internal TcpWebConnection(TcpClient client, TcpWebServer parent, bool ssl)
        {
            m_WaitHandle_Write = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            m_TempBuffer = new ReadWriteBuffer(65535);
            m_IsSSL = ssl;
            m_Segments[0] = string.Empty;
            m_Client = client;
            m_Parent = parent;
            m_RemoteIP = ((IPEndPoint)m_Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();

            if (ssl)
            {
                m_NetworkStream = new SslStream(m_Client.GetStream(), false);
            }
            else
            {
                m_NetworkStream = m_Client.GetStream();
            }

            m_NetworkStream.ReadTimeout = 2000;

            m_Timer_Check = new Timer(Timer_Check_Callback, this, 2000, 2000);

            // start threads
            m_Thread_Read = new Thread(DoRead);
            m_Thread_Read.IsBackground = true;
            m_Thread_Read.Start();
        }

        #endregion constructors

        #region destructors

        ~TcpWebConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                if (m_Timer_Check != null) m_Timer_Check.Dispose();
                m_Timer_Check = null;
            }
            catch { } // if the timer was 
        }

        #endregion destructors

        #region internal properties

        internal bool IsLargeFileUpload { get; set; } = false;

        internal string TempFilename
        {
            get { return m_TempFilename; }
            set { m_TempFilename = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remote IP
        /// </summary>
        internal string RemoteIP
        {
            get { return m_RemoteIP; }
        }

        internal string AbsoluteURI
        {
            get { return m_AbsoluteURI; }
        }

        internal string ContentType
        {
            get { return m_ContentType; }
        }

        internal string[] Segments
        {
            get { return m_Segments; }
        }

        internal NameValueCollection QueryString
        {
            get { return m_QueryString; }
        }

        internal Stream NetworkStream
        {
            get { return m_NetworkStream; }
        }

        internal int ContentLength
        {
            get { return m_ContentLength; }
        }

        #endregion internal properties

        #region private methods

        private void Timer_Check_Callback(object state)
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - m_LastRead).TotalSeconds > 15)
            {
                try
                {
                    Program.BlacklistIP(m_RemoteIP, "TcpWebConnection - Timer", "Connection Timed Out");
                    ProcessRequest(m_ReadData);
                    Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception e) { }
            }
        }

        private void DoRead()
        {
            if (m_IsSSL)
            {
                try
                {
                    ((SslStream)m_NetworkStream).AuthenticateAsServer(m_Parent.ServerCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
                    ((SslStream)m_NetworkStream).BeginRead(m_Buffer, 0, m_Buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(SslRead), m_NetworkStream);
                    m_NetworkStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                    m_NetworkStream.WriteTimeout = 5000;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("SSL Auth Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NormalRead();
            }
        }

        private void UpdatePostData()
        {
            m_FullBuffer.Position = 0;
            byte[] fullBuffer = Common.Conversion.MemoryStreamToByteArray(m_FullBuffer);
            m_FullBuffer.Dispose();

            if (m_StartBoundaryIndex > -1 && m_EndBoundaryIndex > -1)
            {
                m_PostData = new byte[m_EndBoundaryIndex - m_StartBoundaryIndex];
                Array.Copy(fullBuffer, m_StartBoundaryIndex, m_PostData, 0, m_EndBoundaryIndex - m_StartBoundaryIndex);
            }
        }

        internal void SaveFile(string filepath)
        {
            try
            {
                UpdatePostData();
                if (m_PostData == null) return;

                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath));
                }

                if (File.Exists(filepath))
                {
                    File.Delete(filepath);
                }

                using (FileStream output = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    output.Write(m_PostData, 0, m_PostData.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // report error
            }
        }

        private void AppendBuffer(byte[] newBuffer, int length)
        {
            // we need to keep a running buffer here, the last 1024 bytes?  how best to find the end boundary?  need to determine when the stream is finished!
            m_TempBuffer.Write(newBuffer, length);
            if (m_IsFileUpload)
            {
                if (m_EndBoundaryIndex < 0)
                {
                    m_EndBoundaryIndex = StreamHelper.LastIndexOf(m_TempBuffer.RawBytes, m_TempBuffer.Count, m_EndBoundaryBytes);

                    if (!IsLargeFileUpload && m_EndBoundaryIndex > -1)
                    {
                        m_EndBoundaryIndex = (m_FullBuffer.Length + length) - (m_TempBuffer.Count - m_EndBoundaryIndex);
                    }
                }
                if (m_StartBoundaryIndex < 0)
                {
                    m_StartBoundaryIndex = StreamHelper.IndexOf(m_FullBuffer, m_StartBoundaryBytes);

                    if (m_StartBoundaryIndex > -1)
                    {
                        m_StartBoundaryIndex = StreamHelper.IndexOf(m_FullBuffer, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n\r\n"), m_StartBoundaryIndex + m_StartBoundaryBytes.Length) + 4;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (m_StartBoundaryIndex == -1 || !IsLargeFileUpload) // if this is not a file upload because no start boundary has been found then write buffer to memory
            {
                m_FullBuffer.Write(newBuffer, 0, length);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!m_FileCreated) // we have never written to the file, dump the contents of the full buffer now
                {
                    bool exists = true;

                    while (exists)
                    {
                        m_TempFilename = Config.StaticConfig.TempFolder + "/" + Path.GetRandomFileName();
                        exists = File.Exists(m_TempFilename);
                    }

                    m_FileStream = new FileStream(m_TempFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

                    m_FullBuffer.Position = m_StartBoundaryIndex;
                    m_FullBuffer.CopyTo(m_FileStream);
                    m_FileStream.Write(newBuffer, 0, length);

                    m_FileCreated = true;
                }
                else // we have previously written to the file, append new bytes
                {
                    if (m_EndBoundaryIndex == -1)
                    {
                        m_FileStream.Write(newBuffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m_FileStream.Write(newBuffer, 0, length - m_EndBoundaryBytes.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void NormalRead()
        {
            try
            {
                int bufferSize = m_Buffer.Length;
                int bytesRead = m_Client.Client.Receive(m_Buffer, bufferSize, 0);

                while (bytesRead > 0 && !m_IsDisposed)
                {
                    m_LastRead = DateTime.Now;
                    m_BytesRead += bytesRead;

                    if (!m_HasHeaders || m_RequestType == RequestType.GET)
                    {
                        string sBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        m_ReadData += sBuffer;
                    }

                    AppendBuffer(m_Buffer, bytesRead);
                    m_HasHeaders = UpdateUniqueHeaders();

                    if (!m_HasHeaders && m_BytesRead > 1024)
                    {
                        Program.BlacklistIP(m_RemoteIP, m_ReadData, "No HTTP headers found in the first 1024 bytes");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (m_RequestType != RequestType.POST)
                    {
                        break; // process the request
                    }
                    else if (m_EndBoundaryIndex != -1)
                    {
                        break; // process the request, we found our end boundary for posted data
                    }

                    bytesRead = m_Client.Client.Receive(m_Buffer, bufferSize, 0);
                }

                ProcessRequest(m_ReadData);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // report error
            }
        }

        private void SslRead(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            if (m_IsDisposed) return;

            try
            {
                int byteCount = -1;
                int bufferSize = m_Buffer.Length;

                m_LastRead = DateTime.Now;
                byteCount = m_NetworkStream.EndRead(ar);
                m_BytesRead += byteCount;

                if (!m_HasHeaders || m_RequestType == RequestType.GET)
                {
                    string sBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_Buffer, 0, byteCount);
                    m_ReadData += sBuffer;
                }

                AppendBuffer(m_Buffer, byteCount);
                m_HasHeaders = UpdateUniqueHeaders();

                if (!m_HasHeaders && m_BytesRead > 1024)
                {
                    Program.BlacklistIP(m_RemoteIP, m_ReadData, "No HTTP headers found in the first 1024 bytes");
                    return;
                }

                if (byteCount > 0)
                {
                    if (m_RequestType != RequestType.POST && m_RequestType != RequestType.None)
                    {
                        m_NetworkStream.BeginRead(m_Buffer, 0, bufferSize, new AsyncCallback(SslRead), m_NetworkStream);
                    }
                    else if (m_EndBoundaryIndex == -1) // as long as we haven't found the end of the stream continue reading
                    {
                        m_NetworkStream.BeginRead(m_Buffer, 0, bufferSize, new AsyncCallback(SslRead), m_NetworkStream);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return;
            }

            ProcessRequest(m_ReadData);
        }

        private bool UpdateUniqueHeaders()
        {
            if (m_RequestType == RequestType.None && m_ReadData.Length > 8)
            {
                m_RequestType = (m_ReadData.StartsWith("GET ") ? RequestType.GET : m_RequestType);
                m_RequestType = (m_ReadData.StartsWith("POST ") ? RequestType.POST : m_RequestType);
                m_RequestType = (m_ReadData.StartsWith("OPTIONS ") ? RequestType.OPTIONS : m_RequestType);
            }

            if (m_RequestType == RequestType.GET || m_RequestType == RequestType.POST)
            {
                string request = m_ReadData;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_HttpVersion)) m_HttpVersion = m_ReadData.Substring(request.IndexOf("HTTP", 1), 8);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_ContentType)) m_ContentType = GetHeader(request, "Content-Type");
                if (m_ContentLength == 0)
                {
                    int cLength = 0;
                    int.TryParse(GetHeader(request, "Content-Length"), out cLength);
                    m_ContentLength = cLength;

                    if (m_ContentLength / 1024 / 1024 > 20)
                    {
                        IsLargeFileUpload = true; // data is sent directly to a file instead of saving in memory
                    }
                }
            }

            if (m_RequestType != RequestType.None && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_HttpVersion) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_ContentType) || m_RequestType != RequestType.POST))
            {
                if (m_RequestType == RequestType.POST)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (m_IsFileUpload == false)
                        {
                            m_IsFileUpload = Segments[1].Replace("/", "") == "upload";
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }

                    if (m_RequestType == RequestType.POST && m_StartBoundaryBytes == null)
                    {
                        m_StartBoundaryBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetStartBoundary());
                        m_EndBoundaryBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetEndBoundary());
                    }
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_Request) && m_Segments.Length <= 1 && m_QueryString == null)
                {
                    // Extract the Requested Type and Requested file/directory
                    string m_Request = m_ReadData.Substring(0, m_ReadData.IndexOf("HTTP", 1) - 1);

                    //Replace backslash with Forward Slash, if Any
                    m_Request = m_Request.Replace("\\", "/");
                    m_Request = m_Request.Replace("GET ", "");
                    m_Request = m_Request.Replace("POST ", "");

                    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost" + m_Request);
                    NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
                    //SendHeader(sHttpVersion, "image/jpeg", Program.BlankImageBuffer.Length, " 200 OK");

                    m_AbsoluteURI = m_Request;
                    m_Segments = uri.Segments;
                    m_QueryString = query;
                }

                if (m_RequestType != RequestType.POST)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (m_ContentLength > 0 && m_EndBoundaryBytes != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        private string GetStartBoundary()
        {
            return "--" + m_ContentType.Split(';')[1].Split('=')[1];
        }

        private string GetEndBoundary()
        {
            return "--" + m_ContentType.Split(';')[1].Split('=')[1] + "--\r\n";
        }

        private string GetHeader(string request, string key)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            int iStartPos = request.IndexOf(key + ":", 0) + key.Length + 1;

            if (request.IndexOf(key + ":", 0) > -1)
            {
                // Get the HTTP text and version e.g. it will return "HTTP/1.1"
                int iEndPos = request.IndexOf("\r\n", iStartPos);
                result = request.Substring(iStartPos, iEndPos - iStartPos).Trim();
            }

            return result;
        }

        private void CleanFile()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_TempFilename) && File.Exists(m_TempFilename))
                {
                    using (Stream stream = File.Open(m_TempFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        //stream.Position = 0;
                        //stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void ProcessRequest(string request)
        {
            try
            {
                if (request.Length < 5) return;

                List<string> headers = null;
                if (request.StartsWith("OPTIONS"))
                {
                    headers = GetCommonHeader("", 0);
                    headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
                    headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Mashape-Authorization, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-PINGOTHER, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
                    headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS");
                    headers.Add("Keep-Alive: timeout=15,max=100");
                    headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                    headers.Add("Connection: close");

                    SendHeader(headers);
                    return;
                }

                UpdateUniqueHeaders();
                CleanFile();
                CloseFile();

                if (m_Timer_Check != null) m_Timer_Check.Dispose();
                string responseText = Program.ProcessRequest(this);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseText)) responseText = "\r\n";

                byte[] buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseText);
                headers = GetCommonHeader("text/html", buf.Length, " 200 OK");
                headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                SendHeaderAndData(headers, buf);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
            finally
            {
                Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void CloseFile()
        {
            try
            {
                if (m_FileStream != null)
                {
                    m_FileStream.Dispose();
                    m_FileStream = null;
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function send the Header Information to the client (Browser)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sHttpVersion">HTTP Version</param>
        /// <param name="sMIMEHeader">Mime Type</param>
        /// <param name="iTotBytes">Total Bytes to be sent in the body</param>
        /// <param name="mySocket">Socket reference</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<string> GetCommonHeader(string mimeHeader = "text/html", int length = -1, string sStatusCode = " 200 OK", string filename = "", bool chunked = false)
        {
            // if Mime type is not provided set default to text/html

            List<string> headers = new List<string>();

            headers.Add(m_HttpVersion + sStatusCode);
            headers.Add("Server: ExampleTcpWebServer");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeHeader))
            {
                headers.Add("Content-Type: " + mimeHeader);
            }

            if (length > -1)
            {
                headers.Add("Content-Length: " + length);
            }

            headers.Add("Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " GMT");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            {
                headers.Add("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
            }
            if (chunked)
            {
                headers.Add("Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
            }

            return headers;
        }

        public void SendHeader(List<string> headers)
        {
            string sHeader = string.Empty;

            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                sHeader += header + "\r\n";
            }

            sHeader += "\r\n";

            byte[] bSendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sHeader);
            SendToBrowser(bSendData, bSendData.Length);
        }

        public void SendHeaderAndData(List<string> headers, byte[] data)
        {
            string sHeader = string.Empty;

            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                sHeader += header + "\r\n";
            }

            sHeader += "\r\n";

            byte[] bHeader = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sHeader);
            byte[] combined = new byte[bHeader.Length + data.Length];

            Array.Copy(bHeader, combined, bHeader.Length);
            Array.Copy(data, 0, combined, bHeader.Length, data.Length);

            SendToBrowser(combined, combined.Length);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends data to the browser (client)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bSendData">Byte Array</param>
        /// <param name="mySocket">Socket reference</param>
        public void SendToBrowser(byte[] bSendData, int length)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Common.TcpHelper.SocketConnected(m_Client.Client))
                {
                    if (m_IsSSL)
                    {
                        m_NetworkStream.Write(bSendData, 0, length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m_Client.Client.Send(bSendData, length, 0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred : {0} ", e);
            }
        }

        #endregion private methods

        #region IDisposable

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!m_IsDisposed)
            {
                m_IsDisposed = true;

                try
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_TempFilename) && File.Exists(m_TempFilename))
                    {
                        File.Delete(m_TempFilename);
                    }
                }
                catch { }

                CloseFile();

                try
                {
                    m_Client.Client.Close(5);
                    m_Client.Close();
                    m_Client.Client.Dispose();
                }
                catch { }

                try
                {
                    m_NetworkStream.Dispose();
                }
                catch { }

                try
                {
                    if (Thread.CurrentThread != m_Thread_Read && m_Thread_Read.IsAlive)
                    {
                        m_Thread_Read.Join(1000);
                        if (m_Thread_Read.IsAlive) m_Thread_Read.Abort();
                    }
                }
                catch { }

                try
                {
                    m_ReadData = null;
                    m_PostData = null;
                    m_Buffer = null;
                    m_TempBuffer = null;

                    if (m_FullBuffer != null) m_FullBuffer.Dispose();
                    if (m_Timer_Check != null) m_Timer_Check.Dispose();
                    m_Timer_Check = null;
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        #endregion IDisposable
    }
}
```