# Using HttpListener with SSL on Mono

Tags: mono, ubuntu-server, httplistener

I have mono 4.6.2.16 running on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
I cannot use HttpListener to listen for SSL connection. The certificates are OK because NGINX works with them without problem.
This is the error I receive:

```
    Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The client stopped the handshake.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslServerStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x000b9] in <...>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <...>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00057] in <...>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in <...>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate serverCertificate, System.Boolean clientCertificateRequired, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in <...>:0
  at System.Net.HttpConnection.Init() [0x0001d] in <...>:0
  at System.Net.HttpConnection..ctor(System.Net.Sockets.Socket sock, System.Net.EndPointListener epl, System.Boolean secure, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert) [0x00096] in <...>:0
  at System.Net.EndPointListener.ProcessAccept(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs args) [0x00052] in <...>:0
  at System.Net.EndPointListener.OnAccept(System.Object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <...>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) [0x00014] in <...>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.Complete() [0x00000] in <...>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<AcceptAsyncCallback>m__0 (System.IAsyncResult ares) [0x000a0] in <...>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult+<Complete>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (System.Object _) [0x00000] in <...>:0
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() [0x00019] in <...>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() [0x00096] in <...>:0
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() [0x00000] in <...>:0
```

I tried *export MONO_TLS_PROVIDER="btls"* but it didn't help.
The exception looks exactly like [How to I catch SSL exceptions in a Mono HTTPListener server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604945/how-to-i-catch-ssl-exceptions-in-a-mono-httplistener-server)
.NET version the project uses is 4.6.1
How can I solve it without installing new mono version 4.8?

**P.S. After upgrading to mono 4.8.0.489 I'm receiving another error:**

```
    System.IO.IOException: Remote prematurely closed connection.
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0001b] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0009e] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation() [0x0000d] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.StartOperation() [0x00000] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() [0x0000c] in <f712f98eb8e445c8918edaf595bbe465>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication(System.Net.LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) [0x00083] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsServer(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate serverCertificate, System.Boolean clientCertificateRequired, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00010] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.MonoSslStreamWrapper.AuthenticateAsServer(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate serverCertificate, System.Boolean clientCertificateRequired, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00006] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at System.Net.HttpConnection.Init() [0x0001d] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at System.Net.HttpConnection..ctor(System.Net.Sockets.Socket sock, System.Net.EndPointListener epl, System.Boolean secure, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert) [0x00096] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at System.Net.EndPointListener.ProcessAccept(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs args) [0x00052] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at System.Net.EndPointListener.OnAccept(System.Object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) [0x00014] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.Complete() [0x00000] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<AcceptAsyncCallback>m__0 (System.IAsyncResult ares) [0x000a0] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult+<Complete>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (System.Object _) [0x00000] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() [0x00019] in <f712f98eb8e445c8918edaf595bbe465>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() [0x00096] in <f712f98eb8e445c8918edaf595bbe465>:0
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() [0x00000] in <f712f98eb8e445c8918edaf595bbe465>:0
[ERROR]
FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.IOException: Remote prematurely closed connection.
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0001b] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0009e] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation() [0x0000d] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.StartOperation() [0x00000] in <1ad50d57fda24e15afa9ae11713723af>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

**UPDATE: I installed Mono 4.8.0.495 and still have an error:**

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.8.0 (Stable 4.8.0.495/e4a3cf3 Wed Feb 22 18:30:58 UTC 2017)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen

    sudo mono --debug=mdb-optimizations --trace=N:system.Net ./testssl.exe
Starting HTTP server at https://172.16.xx.xx:40510/
[0x7f8a97bb6740:] EXCEPTION handling: Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: MonoBtlsPkcs12.Import failed.
[0x7f8a97bb6740:] EXCEPTION handling: Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: MonoBtlsPkcs12.Import failed.
listening for request...
[0x7f8a8f675700:] EXCEPTION handling: System.IO.IOException: Remote prematurely closed connection.
[0x7f8a8f474700:] EXCEPTION handling: System.IO.IOException: Remote prematurely closed connection.

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.IOException: Remote prematurely closed connection.
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0001b] in <5641e4edad4f4464ba58c620a7b8ea48>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0009e] in <5641e4edad4f4464ba58c620a7b8ea48>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation () [0x0000d] in <5641e4edad4f4464ba58c620a7b8ea48>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.StartOperation () [0x00000] in <5641e4edad4f4464ba58c620a7b8ea48>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: why do you say `without installing mono 4.8`? what problem do you have with that version?

Comment: I have no problem with 4.8 it's just the very version doesn't exist. I don't want to build it from scratch but to use ready binaries.

Comment: please report the 4.8 bug here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Opened bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52675